# Syslog-ng service error on restart - syslog forward to Qradar

Tags: ubuntu, debian, syslog, forwarding, ibm

Hopefully my qeustion is in the right place.

I am currently trying to forward syslogs from an Ubuntu machine to a Qradar machine.
They're on the same network and i already managed to get Rsyslog to work, but it isn't supported by Qradar. Therefore, i had to switch to Syslog-ng.

The official IBM documentation states that it's as easy as adding some lines to the /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf file:

```
 source qr_source {
    internal();
    system();
};
filter qr_filter {
    facility(auth, authpriv);
};
destination qr_destination {
    tcp("<qradar_ip_address>" port(514));
};
log{
    source(qr_source);
    filter(qr_filter);
    destination(qr_destination);
};
```

Unfortunately when i do so and have to restart syslog-ng, it will give me erorrs.

```
******@****:/etc/syslog-ng$ sudo service syslog-ng restart
Job for syslog-ng.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status syslog-ng.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
******@*****:/etc/syslog-ng$ syslog-ng
syslog-ng: Error setting capabilities, capability management disabled; error='Operation not permitted'
[2021-05-23T19:53:13.519942] Error opening control socket, bind() failed; socket='/var/lib/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.ctl', error='Address already in use (98)'
[2021-05-23T19:53:13.536721] Error creating persistent state file; filename='/var/lib/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.persist-', error='Permission denied (13)'
```

Obviously i am sudo user.
I also noticed that the line of code that generate the error is the log related one.
I did add SYSLOGNG_OPTS="--no-caps".
I did try stop and start instead of restart.
I literally have no idea how to proceed here and i'm kind of desperate.
If anyone can offer any help it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest to verify the permissions for the folder `/var/lib/syslog-ng/` this seems to be the root of issue

Comment: as i forgot to think a second way, verify that apparmor or selinux not blocking your try, which would also lead to the same issue